# How to use trim function to remove time from NOW() function

Tags: php, datetime

Let's I have a variable like this:

`$date_posting = 2018-06-12 16:37:13`

Now I want to trim it, so the time would be removed and only the date remains. So it would be something like this:

`$date_posting = 2018-06-12`

So my question is how can I do that with trim function ?

Comment: Do like this `echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date_posting ));`

Comment: Just cut string with `substr()`: https://eval.in/1021075

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create date object and format date.

```
$date_posting = '2018-06-12 16:37:13';
$date_posting = new DateTime($date_posting);
$date_posting = $date_posting->format('Y-m-d');
var_dump($date_posting);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant use the `trim` function.

You should parse the date, then extract the "date" portion.

```
$d = strtotime("2018-06-12 16:37:13"); // 1528810633
date('Y-m-d', $d); // 2018-06-12
```

### Edit:

As mentioned in the comments, this might lead to timezone issues, if the server/client/db is configured properly, then you might want to split the string by using:

```
$arr = explode(' ', '2018-06-12 16:37:13');
// $arr[0] = '2018-06-12'
// $arr[1] = '16:37:13'
```

But that's obviously not the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) instead of [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php).

Like this:

```
$arr = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $date_posting);
// $arr[0] == '2018-06-12'
// $arr[1] == '16:37:13'
```

Comment: This one may be the way to go, as it would not have any chances of timezone interpretation errors by turning a string into a date, and then a date back out as a string through date functions.

Answer (score 0):

As `trim` and `rtrim` removes the ends of a string based on the specified characters, it is not recommended to utilize them as it will not produce the desired results.

Undesired Example: https://3v4l.org/XdKBp

```
$date_posting = '2018-06-12 20:37:13';
var_dump(trim($date_posting, ' 20:37:13')); //undesirable
```

Results:

```
string(5) "8-06-"
```

---

If your date/time string will always use a format of `HH:MM:SS`, an alternative method to `trim` would be to use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to remove the number of characters to the right of the string that represents the time portion.

Example: https://3v4l.org/fD0TU

```
$date_posting = '2018-06-12 16:37:13';
$date_posting = substr($date_posting, 0, -9);
var_dump($date_posting);
```

Results:

```
string(10) "2018-06-12"
```

As `substr` does not provide any validation of the input date value,  I suggest using [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to extract the date from the textual representation of the date/time. Using the expected date format `Y-m-d`. Along with the extra data flag: `+`, which will ignore the time portion of the text in the supplied date.

Example: https://3v4l.org/TVPSO

```
$date_posting = '2018-06-12 16:37:13';
if ($date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d+', $date_posting)) {
    $date_posting = $date->format('Y-m-d');
} else {
    //invalid date supplied
}
var_dump($date_posting);
```

Results:

```
string(10) "2018-06-12"
```

This solution will ensure the supplied date (`$date_posting`) is an acceptable format (`Y-m-d`) or return false. As opposed to parsing an arbitrary string, like `explode(' ', 'hello world')` or `preg_split('/[\s+]/', 'Foo Bar')`.

To optionally require the time portion to be validated within the accepted format, you can alter the format from:

`Y-m-d+` to `Y-m-d H:i:s`

---

Alternatively if you simply want to remove the time portion of the text, you can use `preg_replace` with an appropriate pattern to remove it.

Example: https://3v4l.org/DGbHE

```
$date_posting = '2018-06-12 16:37:13';
$date_posting = preg_replace('/ \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/', '', $date_posting);
var_dump($date_posting);
```

The above solution will not allow you to validate the date portion of the text.

To add date validation to the pattern, you can use parentheses to capture the date portion of the text and use that as your replacement with `$1`.

Example: https://3v4l.org/djfrL

```
$date_posting = '2018-06-12 16:37:13';
$date_posting = preg_replace('/^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$/', '$1', $date_posting);
var_dump($date_posting);
```

Result:

```
string(10) "2018-06-12"
```

---

As you mention `NOW()` in your title and display the resulting value as `2018-06-12 16:37:13`. This leads me to believe you are using a MySQL query to define the `$date_posting` php variable.

If you would like to only retrieve the date portion from the MySQL function `NOW()`, you can alternatively use `SELECT DATE(NOW())`, or if you are retrieving it from a `DATETIME` table column, you can use `SELECT DATE(column_name) AS date_string FROM table_name`. Both of which will result in only the date portion of the text being retrieved.

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0430b/2